# N-th derivative with a recursive function

Tags: python, recursion, derivative

The goal is to use finite differences to write a function that calculates the n-th derivative. The function should be recursive. I have the following suggestion:

```
def deriv_high(f, x, h=0.01, order=1):
    if order == 0:
        return f(x)
    else:
        df = deriv_high(f, x + h, h, order=order - 1) - deriv_high(f, x - h, h, order=order - 1)
        dx = 2 * h
        
        return df / dx
```

It should only do its job for "simple" functions. I have already checked it on some sample functions and it worked perfectly. Now wonder if this is a solution or this is still buggy. What do you think?

Comment: It is moderately accurate. But there are two problems. (1) Unless you use memoisation you will end up evaluating the same function multiple times. (2) You are losing accuracy and ending up with "odd-even decoupling"; for example, in your scheme the second derivative will end up as ( f_(i+2) - 2f_i + f_(i-2) ) / (2h)^2, which both omits the alternate values f_(i+1) and f_(i-1) and effectively uses a stepsize (2h) instead of h.